# My Employer forcing me to enter double billing for two customers

Tags: united-states, clients, billing

My US based fulltime employer forcing me to enter double bill for two customers of 40 hours each. We may be working any where from 40 to 45 hours per week but management forcing us to enter 80 hours total, 40 hours for each client, even though, I may have worked 20 to 25 hours per client.

I have seen double billing is criminal offense and punishable by law. I do not need to do involve in these practices. Is it time to change the employer?

Comment: `I have seen double billing is criminal offense and punishable by law` What country are we talking about here?

Comment: @Flater That's probably not as relevant as you think.  I know of no country were fraud is not a criminal offense or where employment contracts involving criminal activity are enforceable.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: (1) While I admit it's a fringe case, standby contracts can be overlapped; yet technically still can be labeled as double billing. As I said I doubt OP is referring to standby (2) More importantly, the country matters as to how you go about addressing the issue. For Belgium, I would advise speaking to the union, as they generally handle all employee-based complaints and grievances. But different countries have different systems in place

Comment: Working in USA.

Answer (score 14):

The company cannot force you to do anything, if unhappy with their business practices you can always leave or get authorities involved.

I have a guy in a similar situation, I charge a client 40 hours worth a week whether or not my guy actually does 40 hours on a maintenance job. In fact he maintains 2 companies, both of which have agreed to the price. He's on call at either company. That doesn't mean I'm going to have him sitting on his hands half the time.

If they both need him, then I cover him if need be. But so long as they agreed to the price it's fine whether I have one guy servicing or 20, that's my business not theirs.

Comment: I agree with your first sentence, but the rest feels like your clients pay for a flat rate service/maintenance contract, not by the hour, so it does not seems relevant to OP's case.

Comment: @Sclrx yes, in practice they pay a flat rate, but for business reasons it's billed as 40 hours. The OP shouldn't assume something dodgy without full knowledge

Comment: This is the correct answer. The client isn't actually paying for 40 hours, they're paying for a certain level of service and response, but it's quite possible that their accounts department has restrictions.

Answer (score 10):

This is a pretty clear instance of fraud. You need to be led by your own moral compass on exactly how far you want to go on it but if it were me I'd be discreetly looking for a new job ASAP.

Comment: This is not a clear instance of fraud, for all you know the contracts involved call for a minimum of  40 billed hours each week. Unless the details of the contract are known it can't be said if this is clear fraud or not.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would try to get a hard proof about the double billing intent like an email with a neutral question to my manager: did I understand that you want I enter in my timesheet 40 hours for Customer1 and another 40 hours for Customer2 for the same week?

Then I would print or forward those emails to my personal emails for backup purpose.

After that, I will ask to meet 1 on 1 my manager telling him that I am reluctant to do it, can he explain me the reason, if this is agreed by the customers?

If I feel that the manager bullshitted me, I will tell him that I will enter my real time then he will have to override it. While, I will check for another job.

If somehow I get warning, an HR meeting because of my attitude, etc. I would decline to sign anything and if I need to, I willd show that I have proof that they have some gray intents.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**I would immediately consult a lawyer.** If you have done this even once, you could be liable for fraud charges. When I worked for an audit agency, we sent people to jail for this sort of thing. A lawyer can tell you how to best protect yourself.

The next step I would take is immediately starting a job search.

For those who say that the client may be paying for a full-time even if they do not have the work at the time, then it is still necessary to correctly show client hours on the timesheet even if they get billed otherwise according to the contract.

Answer (score -2):

**It could be a test**

Sometimes companies test employees to see if they will do the right thing in a sea of wrongfulness.  Good, honest employees are sometimes hard to find.  You should confirm with whomever is asking you this first, and make sure they indeed want you to do something fraudulent.  Be prepared to tell them "no".  If it's a test, you might just land a promotion!

Personal story:  I had a friend once who had something similar happen to him.  His upper manager was looking for someone to oversee shipping and receiving at a blue collar job.  He brought favored internal candidates in to work a shift, but told them to fudge some of the numbers on the report.  My friend got the promotion because he was the only one to speak up and say that would not do it because it was wrong.

Comment: I'd say this is highly unlikely. Any company that "tests" their employees like this is one you don't want to work for.

Comment: no company does this. no company promotes because you pass a one-off test either.

Comment: @bharal  I've updated my answer with a personal story, this does happen, rarely of course

Comment: @raterus, sounds like a plot line in the movie Courageous.  This subject happened at a business I worked at.  They would "drop" a $5 gift-card to the same store, and whoever picked up and paid with it would get fired.  Whoever reported it, got a pat on the back (no real reward).  I reported a lost $50 bill that belonged to a customer, and the store manager walked out with it.  Fun times.